# show google places api reviews on my site

Tags: google-places-api, review

I have a review site where user can search using google places api autocomplete textbox to find a specific business and write reviews for it on my site.
The google api returns back bunch of stuff along with 5 reviews for the place searched.
is it ok for me to show the reviews the api returns on my site?

Edit:
If yes,

1. do i need to put a disclamer or give credit to google for the
   reviews shown?
2. google place api also returns the review's author name, can i to
   show it? do i need any permission?
3. is it ok for me to copy the google api reviews to my site?

Comment: Ofcourse, as long as you are under the usage limit.

Comment: i have edited my question, please take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are showing a Map, along with that data, the Map must be a Google Map(i.e. that data cannot be accompanied with openstreetmap etc.)

If you are only displaying the reviews, you must show "Powered by Google" with them.

> If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a map, that map must be provided by Google.
>
> If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a page or view that does not also display a Google Map, you must show a "Powered by Google" logo with that data. For example, if your application displays a list of places on one tab, and a Google Map with those places on another tab, the first tab must show the "Powered by Google" logo.

More details here: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/policies

Comment: i am just showing the list of reviews. so all i need to do is add "Powered by Google" logo right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but remember to specifically show one of the provided ones in the zip. The logo cannot be modified in any way.